# How can I run dashing with ruby web server puma?

Tags: ruby, puma, dashing

Dashing uses **thin** ruby web server as default.
I'm trying to used puma as my ruby web server since I got issue with memory consumption with the default web server.

I have read in some **github forums** that the ***rufus-scheduler*** which is used to schedule jobs might be the cause of memory issue.

I set up gem 'puma' in mg GemFile & bundled it.

But every time I run my application, it uses thin web server again.

```
dashing start
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3030, CTRL+C to stop
```

Please help on how to properly use puma web server on dashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your server using `puma`:

`puma config.ru`

Or run your server with [rackup](https://github.com/rack/rack#rackup) and [specify puma](https://github.com/puma/puma#rackup) as the server:

`bundle exec rackup -s puma -p 3030`

Explanation:

When you run `dashing start`, you're using the **dashing CLI tool**. The reason you can't run dashing with `puma` using the dashing CLI tool is because the use of `thin` is hard-coded. See the [dashing CLI code](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/blob/master/lib/dashing/cli.rb#L62).